# Passing a derived class of a base template class as its base template class to a function

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I am implementing an event system where added events are stored into a linked list that I have implemented. When subscribing an event to the event system, I am trying to pass the object of type `EventHandler*`, that is derived from the base template class `IntrusiveLink<T>`, to my linked list's method `void Append(IntrusiveLink<T>* pLink);` as an `EventHandler*`.

I was expecting that it would be upcasted automatically from the 'is-a' relationship of inheritance, but I seem to be misunderstanding what might be actually going on here or I am incorrect in the syntax somehow.

Here is the compiler error.

> cannot convert argument 1 from 'EventHandler*' to 'IntrusiveLink<T>'  with T=EventHandler *. Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires
>   reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

Here is the base template class

```
template <class T> 
class IntrusiveLink
{
    IntrusiveLink<T>* m_pPrev;
    IntrusiveLink<T>* m_pNext;

protected:
    IntrusiveLink()
    : m_pPrev(nullptr), m_pNext(nullptr) {}

public:
    virtual ~IntrusiveLink() {m_pPrev = nullptr; m_pNext = nullptr;}
};
```

Snippet of the derived class of IntrusiveLink

```
class EventHandler : public IntrusiveLink<EventHandler>
{
    // ... other code
};
```

Small snippet of the linked list

```
template <class T> 
class IntrusiveLinkedList
{
    // ... other code

    void Append          (IntrusiveLink<T>* pLink);
};
```

Snippet of the event system header

```
class EventSystem
{
    IntrusiveLinkedList<EventHandler*> m_eventHandlers;

public:

    void  Subscribe   (EventHandler* pEventHandler);

    ... other code
};
```

Finally, the snippet where the error happens

```
void EventSystem::Subscribe(EventHandler* pEventHandler)
{
        // ... other code

        m_eventHandlers.Append(pEventHandler); // Compiler error
}
```

I tried to keep the snippets relevant to the problem, but let me know if you need more information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list template `IntrusiveLinkedList` has a type `EventHandler*`

```
IntrusiveLinkedList<EventHandler*> m_eventHandlers;
```

, so `Append` function expects `IntrusiveLink<EventHandler*>*`, not `IntrusiveLink<EventHandler>*`.
By the way, using templates is not necessary in your example (at least in the part you showed). Inheritance is quite enough.

Comment: Ah I see! Removing the unnecessary template worked perfectly for my code. Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, only pointer to base classes can point to derived instances. to cast from a derive class to a base class, you would have to create a conversion function with: operator baseClass(  );

This is explained in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator

Tough I supose you could make " operator baseClass( baseClass obj ); ", I didnt find such an example, but you can aways test.